# End up vidyo.io conference when admin user exit

Tags: vidyo

I am using vidyo.io api in one of my vidyo.io application. I am not finding any api method to end up a video conference when a admin user will click the disconnect button. This  will disconnect all connected user from the conference.

Help will highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From a conceptual perspective, the Vidyo.io API is intended to manage the local connection to the platform and not to manage conferences (like an admin API), hence there is no way to control conferences by interfering on other users.

I see two ways of doing what you want:

1. In the frontend: whenever there is a change in the list of
   participants check if it is the case to disconnect other users (the admin 
   user left or you are the only one left in the room). If so, disconnect 
   yourself.
2. In the backend (the most reliable way): use your server to monitor
   the conference rooms. Whenever there is a situation where you want to end the 
   call, the server will disconnect everyone **by sending them commands to 
   disconnect themselves**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Alternatively, you can also use the group chat API to send commands to all participants so that they will call the disconnect() method.

The following article should help:
https://vidyo.io/blog/how-to/video-chat-add-text-chat/

Comment: @ Elvis I am having great difficulty on ending a android app hosted vidyo io video call from server but finding no ways even trying nodejs, i summarized the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65232822/ending-the-vidyo-io-video-call-by-server-side-or-other-ways) can you please please answer me there, vidyo io guys don't respond!