# Ending the vidyo io video call by server side or other ways

Tags: javascript, php, android, videocall, vidyo

we are using [vidyo.io](https://vidyo.io/) in our android app where two users are connecting to the vidyo io video call from two android devices using the same our app. we used vidyo.io android sdk in our android app. There are two buttons in the app, one is for ending the video call and the other is for starting/reconnecting the video call.

But for many reasons including internet disconnection what is happening is this - (1) after users finish the video call they forgot to press the end call button. (2) for internet problem both of them disconnected so is they were unable to end the video call pressing the end call button.

As a result of the situations above, vidyo.io taking the video call as active and counting minutes for the duration of the call until call is assumed ended. So is we are seeing a lot of minutes being counted for these calls in vidyo.io usage page for which we need to pay money!!. It's a huge economical problems for us in future when we will have many calls.

So are there any ways to end the vidyo.io video call from server side like from php based server or what other ways??

The way i approached to solve the issue - (1) I search their  [documentation](https://developer.vidyo.io/documentation) thoroughly but did not find any external API to interact with vidyo.io server to end the video call after a interval from the start of the call with fields like resourceId, token, etc. (2) contacted vidyo.io but not getting replies from their support team for various reasons.

so any expert vidyo.io developer here share the ways to overcome the issue and suggest ideas with details and examples of course else it's hard to understand.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: it's all the concept i wrote and it's enough, no coding required to show actually

Answer (score 1):

There's an [article](https://support.vidyocloud.com/hc/en-us/articles/360055684794-Are-there-any-webhook-callbacks-from-the-Vidyo-io-cloud-) on Vidyo's support archive (written 3 months ago as of this writing) which suggests that they currently don't have any server-side solution for such issues:

> Question: Are there any webhook callbacks from the Vidyo.io cloud?

> Answer: No. Everything is currently controlled through the client SDK.

Sounds like you'll have to implement more advanced 'hangup detection' on your own :(

Comment: Could you please write me details about what hangup detection i can use??!, there are no ways left.

Comment: I'm not a Vidyo expert, but as far I know their client sdk supports listeners for events such as 'onDisconnect' and 'onFailure'. You can also track the lifecycle of your android app, and invoke hangup when the app is going to background, or maybe intentionally invoke hangup when network becomes too slow, or something like that.

Comment: then it should be done from the android app sdk codes not from any external server. Because this kind of disconnecting method call can only be done from the sdk where connection was initialized. I was thinking to do from external php server but it's not possible right?

Comment: @developer yes, that was my point in the comments above

Comment: And what about doing it from nodejs without php server?

Comment: Is it possible to initialize a call from nodejs with same token and user which was used in android app to initiate a video call for the user? so that i when i call disconnect() method in nodejs then the call will also be ended in android app for the same user.

Comment: @ electrobuddha can you please answer me ?